# Can we define total boundedness in terms of closed balls of radius $\epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

A set S is totally bounded if for any non-zero $\epsilon$, we find finite number of open balls of radius $\epsilon$ whose union covers S.

In this definition, can we write closed balls in place of open balls? Does it contradict?

Comment: If a finite number of open balls of radius $\epsilon$ covers $S$, then a finite number of closed balls of radius $\epsilon + 1$ covers $S$ as well, since for any $\delta > 0$, $B(x, \epsilon) \subseteq \overline{B}(x, \epsilon + \delta)$. So no, it should be an equivalent definition.

Comment: A set is totally bounded if, for any positive $\varepsilon,$ it is the union of finitely many **sets** of diameter at most $\varepsilon.$ It has nothing especially to do with balls.

Answer (score 2):

If the open balls B(x,r) cover S, then the closed balls B[x,r] cover S.
If the closed balls B[x,r/2] cover S, then the open balls B(x,r) cover S.
Thus the two definitions are equivalent.  The open balls likely will be easier to use.